# Is gzip encoding compatible with JSON?

Tags: php, json, encoding, gzip

I'm trying to narrow down some weirdness going on with my AJAX calls.  My PHP scripts have this at the start:

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
```

Works great with HTML.  But are there any problems with doing it with application/json data?  Any browser issues anyone is aware of?

Comment: Its working fine for me. It correctly send json data with content-encoding gzip in php 5.5.15

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think so... I've used static files stored as gzipped JSON before, and it worked fine with AJAX.

**edit:** I checked my php script and the only thing special I did was to include these headers:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/plain
```

If I remember right, whenever I tried to change the Content-Type to something that would indicate JSON, the client had trouble.

Comment: Thats interesting. I use application/json cos I thought thats what you should do for json.

Comment: I'm trying to remember the exact issue I had. It may have been that the AJAX part didn't mind, but for debugging it was a big pain because Firefox doesn't know how to display application/JSON, whereas it works fine with text/plain.

Comment: (by "debugging" I mean viewing the JSON url directly in my browser, rather than by putting breakpoints/logging in the AJAX part of my application)

Answer (score 3):

Some older browsers, like certain versions of IE6, screw up gzipped content, especially js content.

Just check that your server sends proper content-encoding header, that is

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

You should also check the headers sent by the browser for proper accept-encoding header before sending gzipped content... that is,

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

Comment: That's the idea with ob_gzhandler

Answer (score 2):

You can give out gzipped content whenever the browser specifies `gzip` in `Accept-Encoding` request header. In that case, there is no difference between JSON and HTML and no problems will be caused whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of enabling compression in PHP, I would enable compression in Apache (using mod_deflate) so that you can check for various incompatible browsers and only send compressed data for the browsers that accept it and handle it correctly.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html

Comment: Thats what ob_gzhandler does. I prefer programmatic control.